# An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ovning_grunder5._1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input;
            int[] tal1;
            int i = 0;
            int count = 0;
            int large = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Mata in tal och avsluta med 0");
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            while (input != "0")
            {
                tal1[i] = Convert.ToInt32(input); //Error Occurres here after the second input is given.
                input = Console.ReadLine();
                i++;
                Console.WriteLine(tal1[i]);
            }
            while (tal1[count] <= i)
            {
                if (tal1[count] < large)
                {                        
                    large = tal1[count];
                }
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the program, I add input breaks in my program and gives the error `"An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred."` Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I'm surprised it's an OutOfRangeException. As far as that code shows tal1 is always null.

Comment: You never initialize any values in `tal1`.  So there's nothing at index `i`.

Answer (score 0):

if you know the size of array you need, then first initialize with the size as below

```
int[] tal1 = new int[10];
```

otherwise you can use `List<int>`

```
List<int> tal1 = new List<int>();
while (input != "0")
{
  tal1.Add(Convert.ToInt32(input));
  input = Console.ReadLine();
}
large = tal1.Max();
```

Comment: I changed the array to int[] tal1= new int[100]; and it still reports an error on the second input An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring tal1 as an array, but you're never initializing it. I'd recommend using a generic list instead of an array here:

```
var tal1 = new System.Collections.Generic.List<int>();
```

Comment: How do you mean "I do not initialzie it"?

Comment: The code you posted tells the compiler that `tal1` is a **static** array of integers. However, the code doesn't specify how many elements are in the array. The CLR never set aside any memory for the array - so it was never initialized.

Comment: Honestly, I can't even get the code you posted to compile in Visual Studio 2012, so I can't reproduce that behavior. I would expect it to fail as soon as it tried to parse your first line of input.